# probability to get 2 cards with the same rank

Tags: probability

Divide a deck of (52) cards to 4 players.

what is the probability that player A gets at least 2 cards with the same rank?

Comment: Could you please show some of your work?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: What is the probability that every card that player A gets has a different rank? How can we use that to find the probability we're interested in? The other players will not matter to the problem, so don't worry about them.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the only possibilty of player $A$ not to have at least 2 cards with the same rank is when they are with different ranks, because there are $13$ ranks and also the player $A$ gets $13$ cards. This follows from the pigeonhole principle.

Because the order doesn't matter, let Ace be the first cards, two the second and so on. Then we have $4$ options for every rank, because there are $4$ cards from the same rank in a deck of cards. So the number of $13-cards$ hands when all of the ranks are different is:

$$4^{13}$$

While the number of all $13-cards$ hand from a standard deck is: $$\binom{52}{13}$$

And the total probabilty is:

$$P = \frac{4^{13}}{\binom{52}{13}}$$

Now simplify this by yourself.